# How to display custom errors in the template

Tags: python, django

I have function with custom errors, how to display these errors in the template

```
def auth_join(request, room, slug):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user.username
    form_auth = AuthRoomForm(request.POST)
    if form_auth.is_valid():
        room_pass = form_auth.cleaned_data.get('room_pass')
        password2 = form_auth.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if room_pass != password2:
            messages.error(request, 'Doesn\'t match')
            return HttpResponse('error')
        else:
            # messages.success(request, 'match')
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user)
            room = get_object_or_404(Room, slug=slug)
            if user.has_perm('pass_perm', room):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(Room.get_absolute_url(room))
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You don\'t have access to this page')
else:
    form_auth = AuthRoomForm()

return render(request,'rooms/auth_join.html', {'form_auth':form_auth})
```

I mean maybe try to do something like that,what i should use istead HttpResponse and how to implement in the template

```
{% if form_auth.errors %}
   {% for field in form_auth  %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <div class="ui red message">
        {{error}}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do the error checking in the view but in the form (your `AuthRoomForm`). That's all. If you [raise validation errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) in your form's `clean` or `clean_<fieldname>` methods they will automatically be added to your `form.errors` and `field.errors`. So that if the form is not valid your view just returns the same template with the bound form with errors.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really want to do this in your view, add the errors to the form (`form.add_error(ValidationError('You don't have access to this page'))`) which will also do the trick. Again, don't return `HttpResponse` in case of error, just `render` the template with the form (which you already do at the end of your view).

Answer (score 0):

You template is showing all the form's errors. So you just need to make sure that the validation errors are added to the `form`, and that's not done by returning an `HttpResponse` with just an error string.

You have two options:

- Preferred route is to perform all validation in your form `AuthRoomForm`, not in your view. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/) explains all the ways to add custom validation to your form, most common is to use the `clean()` and `clean_<fieldname>()` methods.
- If you really want to do this in your view, just use the [`form.add_error()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method, e.g. `form.add_error(ValidationError('You don\'t have access to this page'))`.

In both cases, if the form isn't valid, don't `return HttpResponse(<error>)`. Just `render()` your template with the bound form, as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#the-view) and in every starter Django tutorial about Django forms.

Comment: thanks,and one more thing i want to improve that with ajax,do you know any example of that?

Comment: As I said earlier, if you google a bit for django + Ajax you’ll find plenty of examples